# Empty String Mystery

Tags: visual-c++, mfc

I am publicly declaring a variable called currentDocName in my View class.

```
CString currentDocName = (CString)"Emergence1";
```

Later on in that same class I call an OutputDebugString with currentDocName as its input. However, it appears to be an empty string. How could this be? Nowwhere else am I initialising currentDocName to an empty string.

Comment: You haven't given us enough information. Please copy your code into a new project and remove everything except the very minimum amount that shows the problem. That alone may help you discover the error. If not, please post the problematic code in its entirety.  See http://www.sscce.org/

Comment: Why don't you initialise the variable like this: `CString currentDocName = _T("Emergence1");`, or like this: `CString currentDocName(_T("Emergence1"));`? Why do you use this C-style cast to CString? Please use _T() macro to easily convert you project to/fro UNICODE

Answer (score 0):

That line of code declares a local variable, not a public variable: It will be destroyed when the enclosing function returns. Does "later on in the same class" mean in some other class function?

Comment: i don't see how it could be a local variable...i put it outside any function straight after my includes statements. furthermore i defined it in the header file as public...Nevertheless, to answer your question yes, i meant in some other class function.

Comment: Show all the code that declares/defines/uses this variable.